# How can I retrieve childnodes of a node in the order they appear in the XML document?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am using DOM parser to access an XML document and retrieve some values. The problem is that while I need to load the values in a list in the exact order they appear in the XML, the parser returns the values of the childnodes in random order.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
<scene id="mainMenu">
<sprite src="menubackground.png" position="0 0 0 0 0 0 200 200" visibility="true" name="background"/>
</scene> 
</xml>
```

and the code I am using:

```
public class readXML2 {


public static void main(String [ ] args){
    String[] temp = new String[4];
    String sceneId = "mainMenu";
    Document doc;
    List<Node> sceneItems = new ArrayList<Node>();
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\manolaki\\Desktop\\assetsBACK.xml");

    try{
        builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = builder.parse(file);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();


    for (int h = 0; h < doc.getElementsByTagName("scene").getLength(); h++){ 
        if (doc.getElementsByTagName("scene").item(h).getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue().equals(sceneId)){
            for (int t=0; t< doc.getElementsByTagName("scene").item(h).getChildNodes().getLength(); t++ )
                if (doc.getElementsByTagName("scene").item(h).getChildNodes().item(t).getNodeType() != Node.TEXT_NODE)
                    sceneItems.add(doc.getElementsByTagName("scene").item(h).getChildNodes().item(t));
        }
    }



    for (int i=0; i <sceneItems.size(); i++){
        for (int j=0; j < 4/*sceneItems.get(i).getAttributes().getLength()*/; j++){
            temp[j] = sceneItems.get(i).getAttributes().item(j).getNodeValue();
            System.out.println(temp[j]);
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();  }


}

}
```

The values appear in the console like this:

```
background
0 0 0 0 0 0 200 200
menubackground.png
true
```

But I need This:

```
 menubackground.png
 0 0 0 0 0 0 200 200
 true
 background
```

I think DOM reads the XML in a tree structure but I am not sure how exactly its working and how I can get the values in the right order constantly for different childnodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the XML specs the attributes of an element are a *set* of name/value pairs, with no defined ordering.  A parser or DOM API is free to return them in any order it wants to, in fact the JavaDoc for `NamedNodeMap` states that

> `NamedNodeMap`s are not maintained in any particular order. Objects contained in an object implementing `NamedNodeMap` may also be accessed by an ordinal index, but this is simply to allow convenient enumeration of the contents of a `NamedNodeMap`, and does not imply that the DOM specifies an order to these Nodes.

You could dump the `NamedNodeMap` into a `List` or an array and sort that lexicographically by node name, which would give you a consistent order across all the elements, but there's no way to know the order in which the attributes were specified in the original XML source via the DOM API.

Comment: So, is there anything I can do to work around it? or maybe use another parser?

Comment: @user3433393 this isn't a matter of which parser you're using, it's part of the definition of what XML _is_ that "the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant" [XML spec, sec. 3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags).  You could try using a StAX XMLStreamReader instead of DOM - as a cursor-based API it's more likely to respect the original order (though I can't find anything in the docs that says this is necessarily guaranteed).

Answer (score 0):

If you need the order, use actual child elements, not attributes, like this:

```
<sprite>
 <src>menubackground.png</src>
 <position>0 0 0 0 0 0 200 200</position>
 <visibility>true</visibility>
 <name>background</name>
</sprite>
```

(If you are not in the position to define the structure of the XML, then you may try implementing a simple parser yourself to work around the design flaw - if advanced XML features are not expected in the input.)

Edit:
What about loading the attributes into a java object, then you can output them as you like.

Comment: The thing is there will be a lot of scenes containing a lot of sprites and also the XML becomes 3-level deep so the code will increase noticeably. I will try load the values into a list and sort them alphabetically to get some consistency and if that doesn't work I will probably use actual child elements. Thanks anyway, this is an interesting approach too.

Comment: In this case consider taking the expensive calls out of the loops to avoid slowing down. Instead of using `t < doc.getElementsByTagName("scene").item(h).getChildNodes().getLength()` as a loop condition you can put it into a variable first.